# Importing google polymer in Orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms, polymer, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying below

```
RegisterLink(new LinkEntry { Rel = "import", Href = Url.Content("~/Themes/SomeTheme/components/font-roboto/roboto.html") });
```

in my orchid layout, for using polymer. however this request is throwing a 404(on network tab in chrome.).

I am very much new to Orchid cms and hence struggling with this. Any help on this.

Note: I found that I have a class ResourceManager which implements IResourceManager. I am not sure if this is where I need to do make some changes. So adding this note as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a web.config inside Themes/SomeTheme/components folder (same as ThemeMachine/Styles) making one modification:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
```

Remove (if existing) all web.config files in children folders.

Comment: thanks for this. It works. I found this out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626611/placing-js-files-in-the-views-folder.  I was about to update this as answer and found u. :)

Answer (score 0):

You really need a web server to host polymer assets unless you disable web security. It can be any web server server. In addition, the ~ directive probably wouldn't be recognized by chrome file loader.