# Why can't I put the webform into Views/Home folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2.0 (C#) within Webform.

When I follow this step: `right click solution -> Add -> New item... -> create new webform`

After debugging, that's work without a problem when I type **"localhost/webform1.aspx"** on url.

But, when I do this: `right click Views\Home folder -> Add -> Web form -> ok`

In `HomeController.cs`

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
return View("webform2");
}
```

In `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebForm}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

It gave to me an error when I type **"localhost/home/test"** on url:

```
The view at '~/Views/home/webform2.aspx must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>...'
```

My question is: Can't webform be created in Views\Home folder?

If possible, can you tell me how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: why you're using a webform in a mvc application and why not using a .cshtml view file for the controller function instead of using webforms?

Comment: because I want to use some server controls like: panel and gridview. it's easy to use by webform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Views` folder have web.config file that blocks access to all items in that folder an below.

Fix:

- update Views\web.config to allow access as covered in [Placing js files in the views folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626611/placing-js-files-in-the-views-folder)
- Put web forms to they own folder

Comment: mm..... sorry, I still don't know how to update View\web.config as your advice. Can it be clearly more? Thanks

Comment: @TânNguyễn I've added link.